# Get HtmlDocument after javascript manipulations

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control, dom

In C#, using the System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument class (or another class that allows DOM parsing), is it possible to wait until a webpage finishes its javascript manipulations of the HTML before retrieving that HTML?  Certain sites add innerhtml to pages through javascript, but those changes do not show up when I parse the HtmlElements of the HtmlDocument.

One possibility would be to update the HtmlDocument of the page after a second.  Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Someone revived this question by posting what I think is an incorrect answer. So, here are my thoughts to address it.

Non-deterministically, it's possible to get close to finding out if the page has finished its AJAX stuff. However, it completely depends on the logic of that particular page: some pages are perpetually dynamic.

To approach this, one can handle `DocumentCompleted` event first, then asynchronously poll the `WebBrowser.IsBusy` property and monitor the current HTML snapshot of the page for changes, like below.

The complete sample can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20934538/1768303).

```
// get the root element
var documentElement = this.webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0];

// poll the current HTML for changes asynchronosly
var html = documentElement.OuterHtml;
while (true)
{
    // wait asynchronously, this will throw if cancellation requested
    await Task.Delay(500, token); 

    // continue polling if the WebBrowser is still busy
    if (this.webBrowser.IsBusy)
        continue; 

    var htmlNow = documentElement.OuterHtml;
    if (html == htmlNow)
        break; // no changes detected, end the poll loop

    html = htmlNow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general aswer is "no" - unless script on the page notifies your code in some way you have to simply wait some time and grab HTML. Waiting a second after document ready notification likley will cover most sites (i.e. jQuery's `$(code)` cases).

Comment: I'm okay with waiting a second, but how do I get the updated HTML after a second?  The HtmlDocument property of the WebBrowser object is still the outdated DOM.

Comment: Body.InnerHtml should give you latest version of the DOM. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171712.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the application a second to process the Java. Simply halting the current thread will delay the java processing as well so your doc will still come up outdated.

```
WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs cachedLoadArgs;

private void TimerDone(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Timer)sender).Stop();
    respondToPageLoaded(cachedLoadArgs);
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    cachedLoadArgs = e;

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new Timer();

    int interval = 1000;

    timer.Interval = interval;
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerDone);
    timer.Start();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What about using 'WebBrowser.Navigated' event?

Comment: I wait until navigation is complete before getting the DOM, but it's still the outdated DOM.

Answer (score -1):

I made with WEbBrowser take a look at my class:

```
public class MYCLASSProduct: IProduct
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    private WebBrowser _WebBrowser;
    private AutoResetEvent _lock;

    public void Load(string url)
    {
        _lock = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        this.Url = url;

        browserInitializeBecauseJavascriptLoadThePage();
    }

    private void browserInitializeBecauseJavascriptLoadThePage()
    {
        _WebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        _WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
        _WebBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        _WebBrowser.Name = "webBrowser";
        _WebBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        _WebBrowser.TabIndex = 0;
        _WebBrowser.Navigate(Url);

        Form form = new Form();
        form.Hide();
        form.Controls.Add(_WebBrowser);

        Application.Run(form);
        _lock.WaitOne();
    }

    private void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        hDocument.LoadHtml(_WebBrowser.Document.Body.OuterHtml);
        this.Price = Convert.ToDouble(hDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='ask']").FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim());
        _WebBrowser.FindForm().Close();
        _lock.Set();

    }
```

if your trying to do this in a console application, you need to put this tag above your main, because Windows needs to communicate with COM Components:

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
```

I did not like this solution, But I think that is no one better!

Comment: How does this address the DOM changes made *after* `DocumentCompleted` has been fired?