# WebBrowser document.body.InnerHtml returns empty?

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control, innerhtml, innertext

There is a Page, I want to get it's body for reading input areas, and changing their values by GetAttribute and SetAttribute in C#. This is no problem to do it but,

There is nothing returns (I mean empty string), when I call the body via:

```
webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText
```

or,

```
webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml
```

That's why I can't acces any input field.
I see The Web Page in webbrowser component, But Neither InnerText nor InnerHtml return. It's a saved Bank weppage running on local.

So How can I read body, for running SetAttribute or GetAttribute  or InvokeMember something else?

Comment: Do you wait until the page is completely loaded? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957182/load-url-from-txt-file-and-load-the-url-in-browser-synchronous-webclient-httpreq

Comment: When do you call webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText.  Immediate after loading page in webbrowser control?

Comment: Yeah completely loaded.How I dont know but Problem solved. Perhabs I missed something. I get only Frame tags. Then I tryed to acces into each frames by code: webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[i].Document.Body.InnerHtml And that works

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to get the input element then to get or set the text :

```
HtmlElementCollection elements = currentBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT");
     foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
        {
           //to get the text use :  string value = element.GetAttribute("value");
           //to set the text use :  elemet.InnerText = "something";

        }
```

but don't forget that by the code above you get all the input elements , to search for a specific element you can check its id or name as in the webpage : for example :

```
 if (element.Name.ToLower().Contains("email"))
         //do work
```

Comment: @AliCAKIL, out of curiosity, how did this answer solved your problem?