# Why getting webBrowser's state only works if using another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer, webbrowser-control

I want to wait until `browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete`. There's `DocumentCompleted` Webbrowser's event, but if the page is being loaded by using AJAX it does fire when the HTML is ready, the missing contentes being loaded by ajax isn't available at this time.
My first ide was:

```
int[] myFunction() {

  int[] values;

 while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
         Application.DoEvents();
  }
             values = get_values_from_browser();
  return values;
}
```

it doesn't works return soon than it should and I get wrong value in the array, for example, all the elements are the same. However, if I use a `Timer` it does Works (I get correct values in the array) but I can't return from the function because I don't know when return from function.

The timer is:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
     int[] myFunction() {

      int[] values;
      timer1.Interval = 1000;
                timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate(object o, EventArgs ea)
                    {
                            if (browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                            {
                                timer1.Stop();
                                values = get_values_from_browser();
                            }
                    });
                timer1.Start();
          return values;
    }
```

**So my question is**: Why it does works using a new thread (the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`) but doesn't with the `while` loop in the main thread? any `Thread.Sleep(x)` in the main case will make it work.

Comment: If the first piece of code runs from the UI thread, you are probably blocking the browser from doing any work since you occupy the thread and never let any other computing happen on it.

Comment: Actually, I'm not. I'm using `Application.DoEvents();` forget to type it here

Comment: I can't say I know for sure why it's not working, so this is not an answer to your question. But the second implementation with the timer is the better way to go even if the first solution would work. You can even decrease the timer interval and get a responsive UI as opposed to the first solution.

Comment: @MotiAzu: The problem with the second solution is: after `timer1` is stopped and the function to extract data from webBrowser is called, I'd like to return to function. But how could I do that?

Comment: You can use a callback delegate, here's an example https://gist.github.com/motiazu/e614a48b577f45001102

Comment: Which web browser control are you using?

Comment: @MotiAzu: It seems to be a nice solution. But it implies in some changes the "design" of my program: rather than hold all the return value from `get_values_from_browser()` into an array and then process them I should process them on-the-fly instead of....

Comment: @JohnSaunders: This one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I added the [tag:winforms] and [tag:webbrowser-control] tags to your question, so that's clearer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Thanks. I edited title too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AJAX page is non-deterministic. E.g., its JavaScript logic might be using its own timers to make XHR requests, in which case `browser.ReadyState` wouldn't be a reliable indicator of any pending activity.
Moreover, I'm not even sure XHR request themselves count towards `browser.ReadyState`. [`WebBrowser.IsBusy`](http://WebBrowser.IsBusy) is more likely to account for that. On a side note, don't use `Application.DoEvents()`, in most cases [it's a pure evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/06/448560.aspx).

To solve the problem, you could use asynchronous polling. I've answered a similar question with some sample code here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20934538/1768303.

Comment: I don't know why but I wasn't notified about your answer on this topic. That's why I just tried it now. Thank you SO much, man. It worked *exactly* as I wanted. I've working on it for several days trying a lot of differents approachs and Reading about thread to try get some help. Have a nice day.

Comment: I could give you 50+ if I can but that question doesn't have bounty.

Comment: @Jack, no worries, glad it helped. I have some other related answers, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239357/how-to-cancel-task-await-after-a-timeout-period/22262976#22262976

Comment: It has been 3th time you saved my life when using WebBrowser. You have so much skills man. I favorited that topic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your first method you're doing:

```
int[] myFunction() {

   int[] values;

   while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
        values = get_values_from_browser();
        Application.DoEvents();
   }

   return values;
}
```

shouldn't this be:

```
int[] myFunction() {

   int[] values;

   while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
       Application.DoEvents();
   }

   values = get_values_from_browser();
   return values;
```

}

Comment: yes, it is. I type that code here the SO's textarea and forget it. But it doesn't Works anyway