# WPF Webbrowser cannot display Angular

Tags: wpf, angular

I am trying to embed an Angular web app in WPF.

I have followed the steps [here](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) to create a very basic angular application.
Then I created a brand new WPF application, added a WebBrowser control and set its Source property equal to the URL of the angular application.

I found the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449755/wpf-webbrowser-fails-to-load-rendered-html-of-an-angular-js-website) but it did not help.

I get the following error when the WPF application starts.

"Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference"
in the vendor.bundle.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error the meta tag fixed it. Originally I was putting outside the head tag. Adding it to head tag fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The default WebBrowser object that .Net applications are using it is IE7 I guess..

I've found a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776951/set-wpf-webbrowser-control-to-use-ie10-mode) for making WebBrowser to use IE10 or IE11 (Edge).

Another solution is to use third-party WebBrowsers, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119125/options-for-embedding-chromium-instead-of-ie-webbrowser-control-with-wpf-c) is an old article but I think it might help.

Comment: Ok let me try that.

Comment: I tried that, adding a value with name of my application and setting the emulation value. It did not solve my problem.